# Recognize date format

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

What date format is this?

```
2012-06-08dT00:00:00Z
```

And how can i convert a timestamp in php to this date format?

Comment: why do you need that specific format?

Comment: it would be ISO 8601 if the 'd' weren't there.

Comment: are you sure that this is ISO 8691?
In php docs it says: ISO-8601 (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000)

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-06-08T00:00:00Z'); //with no 'd'
$timestamp = $dt->format('U');
```

If you must have the 'd', then:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d??H:i:s?', '2012-06-08dT00:00:00Z');
$timestamp = $dt->format('U');
```

ETA: timestamp -> your format

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1339124400');  //the @ indicates the following number is a timestamp
$isoformat= $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sZ'); //leave out the 'd' and escape the 'T'
```

Comment: maybe i don't explain me in the right way: i have the unix timestamp and I want to convert it in a format like '2012-06-08dT00:00:00Z' (yes, maybe the d is an error)

Comment: @OscarFanelli: sorry about that. I've added info for timestamp to format.

Answer (score 0):

here is something for you to start from:

```
$date = "2012-06-08dT01:02:03Z";

// parse the date correctly
$parsed_date = date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d  H:i:s ', $date);
print_r($parsed_date);

// Make time from parsed date
$old_date = mktime($parsed_date['hour'], $parsed_date['minute'], $parsed_date['second'], $parsed_date['month'], $parsed_date['day'], $parsed_date['year']);

$now_date = time();

// a silly way to print that parsed date into the original way as before
echo date("Y-m-d", $old_date) . 'dT' . date("H:i:s", $old_date) . 'Z';
echo "\n";

// a silly way to print current date/time in that format
echo date("Y-m-d", $now_date) . 'dT' . date("H:i:s", $now_date) . 'Z';
```